# "Scope to this" operation for methods

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper, resharper-8.0, resharper-9.0

Is there a way to scope to a method?

I mean, if I have 10 projects but want to work with only one, I can scope to it, so that the others don't appear to clutter my screen.

As it's useful, it would be great if there was a way to scope to a method in a class and only see it in the code editor.

I have Visual Studio 2013 and ReSharper 9, and could not find something like that anywhere. =(